# Website Section Dependent Header Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a site right now for a client, the demo is up at "[Link is here](http://www.domfarolino.com/roofrenew)" and I am trying to make it so when you click on a link in the header navigation, it scrolls to that section of the website.

I have no problem doing that, I have done that on my "[Site](http://www.domfarolino.com)", but beyond that i would like it so that if you scroll down on your own and you pass a certain section, its link on the "Nav Menu" automatically highlights as you pass over it. Does that make sense?

So if there are 6 sections and 6 links on the header "Nav", if you begin scrolling down, as you scroll down from top to bottom, the menu links will highlight as if you were hovering over them with your mouse, but you are not, they are just activated because you are viewing them on screen.

I imagine this would be a Javascript or jQuery thing but I'm not sure where to start with that.

Comment: Paragraph breaks. Please.

Comment: sounds like you want something like [scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy)